# Conditionally expose filter

Tags: users, views

I have a view for which I want to expose a filter only to users with certain roles and/or permissions. For users without, I do not want them to be able to use this exposed filter. The documentation for [hook_views_pre_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) isn't clear on whether it can be used to modify exposed filters. How would I go about conditionally hiding/removing an exposed filter in code?

Comment: I agree with MPD's answer, but if you do want to do it programmatically, I did some proof of concept code recently that added a field to the table output if a value was entered into the associated filter. It uses hook_views_pre_build(), and was based on these resources: [Views API Exposed](http://2012.drupaldownunder.org/session/views-api-exposed) and [Views Dynamic Fields](http://drupalcode.org/project/views_dynamic_fields.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-1.x). HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a view with your base settings, and then make two displays: one with the exposed filter, and then one without.  Then use your normal access control methods to show the proper display at the proper setting.

For example, if you use views-as-blocks, add visibility rules.  If you use panels, use a new page variant w/ access settings, or add access settings to the content pane.

Otherwise, your best option is to implement the view hooks and experiment.  See what `$view` looks like with the exposed filter and without.  Add your logic, and make the one look like the other.  Unfortunately, what you can do in view hooks is rather sparsely documented; I always tackle this through trial and error.

Comment: Accepting because this is better than what I did, although my specific case doesn't allow this solution. My solution below is very brittle and can't be imported/exported by Views, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing (no guarantees about it being the best way, but it's up [on drupal.org awaiting the maintainer's feedback](https://drupal.org/node/1845160#comment-6838922)):

For the filter in question I changed

```
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
```

to

```
global $user;
if((in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) ||
    (user_access('view own unpublished content') == TRUE) ||
    (user_access('bypass node access') == TRUE)) {
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
} else {
  $handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = FALSE;
}
```

Which exposes the filter in question if any one of the following three conditions are met:

1. The current user has role "administrator"
2. The current user has permission "view own unpublished content"
3. The current user has permission "bypass node access"

It would be better if Drupal had a "view unpublished content" blanket permission, or a "view unpublished [foo] content" for each node type, but in the absence of such controls, these three conditions seem like they would be adequate for the vast majority of use cases.